# Why is my ISP box talking to my DMZ host?

Tags: iptables, dmz, shorewall

I have a setup where an internet connection is available via ISP box, which has a DMZ feature (one of the hosts can be exposed to Internet). The general setup is the following

```
Internet - PublicIP - 192.168.0.254 - 192.168.0.10
           [ FAI box               ]  [ my server - interface int0]
```

The server (wired connection to the ISP box) runs `shorewall` which builds appropriate `iptables` rules. The logs shows, among others, the following repeated entry:

```
May 22 18:59:26 srv kernel: [ 1017.353898] Shorewall:int-fw:REJECT:IN=int0 OUT= MAC=40:8d:5c:4b:aa:55:b8:26:6c:c9:bc:34:08:00 SRC=192.168.0.254 DST=192.168.0.10 LEN=427 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=38328 DPT=5784 LEN=407
```

It therefore looks like

- a device with IP `192.168.0.254` (which is the internal IP of the ISP box, and the gateway for my server) is attempting
- to talk to device `192.168.0.10` (my host - in the FAI box DMZ) on udp/5784
- and this connection is rejected - which is expected as no connection sourced from 'outside' should reach `192.168.0.10`. 'outside' is normally Internet but here it is the gateway of the server.

**What could be the reason for such a connection?** It is always `udp/5784` which IANA [assigns](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml?&page=95) to *Cisco Interbox Application Redundancy*.

In contrast, a typical noise from Internet is reject with an expected log (source IP on Internet, directed to the public IP address which is translated to `192.168.0.10` as the host is in the DMZ and gets all packets)

```
May 22 19:22:03 srv kernel: [ 2345.529390] Shorewall:int-fw:REJECT:IN=int0 OUT= MAC=40:8d:5c:4b:aa:55:b8:26:6c:c9:bc:34:08:00 SRC=113.162.106.145 DST=192.168.0.10 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=47 ID=51469 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=47041 DPT=23 WINDOW=14520 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the packet, it ended up being a UPnP call from the box to all attached devices.

Disabling UPnP fixed the problem (no more packets detected).